# unable to access usb device

Tags: 10.04, boot, usb, devices, pci

I'm reading my boot logs, at `/var/log` trying to understand why the boot process is taking so long.

I found that the system can't access many usb devices, but can't understand why.

Is there a way to stop Ubuntu from trying to access them?

Here are the lines:

> /var/log# grep -r "usb_id" .
> ./boot.log:usb_id[716]: unable to
> access
> '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:1.0/input/input7/mouse1'
> ./boot.log:usb_id[721]: unable to
> access
> '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:1.0/input/input7/event7'
> ./boot.log:usb_id[725]: unable to
> access
> '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:1.0/input/input7/event7'
> ./syslog:Jan 12 21:12:05 TomsterInc
> usb_id[955]: unable to access
> '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:1.0/input/input16/event16'
> ./syslog:Jan 12 21:12:05 TomsterInc
> usb_id[956]: unable to access
> '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:1.0/input/input16/mouse3'
> ./syslog:Jan 12 21:12:05 TomsterInc
> usb_id[963]: unable to access
> '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:1.0/input/input16/event16'
> ./daemon.log:Jan 12 21:12:05
> TomsterInc usb_id[955]: unable to
> access
> '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:1.0/input/input16/event16'
> ./daemon.log:Jan 12 21:12:05
> TomsterInc usb_id[956]: unable to
> access
> '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:1.0/input/input16/mouse3'
> ./daemon.log:Jan 12 21:12:05
> TomsterInc usb_id[963]: unable to
> access
> '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:1.0/input/input16/event16'

## update

Not sure if it helps, but here's the list of my PCI devices

```
PCI Devices
-----------

-PCI Devices-
Host bridge     : Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Graphics Port (rev 07)
USB Controller      : Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
USB Controller      : Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
USB Controller      : Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
USB Controller      : Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03) (prog-if 20)
Audio device        : Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03)
USB Controller      : Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
USB Controller      : Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
USB Controller      : Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
USB Controller      : Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03) (prog-if 20)
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93) (prog-if 01)
ISA bridge      : Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
SATA controller     : Intel Corporation ICH9M/M-E SATA AHCI Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 01)
SMBus       : Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
VGA compatible controller       : ATI Technologies Inc Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series
Audio device        : ATI Technologies Inc RV620 Audio device [Radeon HD 34xx Series]
Network controller      : Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g (rev 01)
Ethernet controller     : Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
FireWire (IEEE 1394)        : Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 10)
SD Host controller      : Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22) (prog-if 01)
System peripheral       : Ricoh Co Ltd R5C843 MMC Host Controller (rev 12)
System peripheral       : Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 12)
System peripheral       : Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pull the devices out? what devices are they?

Comment: @Roland. I have no devices connected, is there any way to know ?

Comment: install hardinfo, and go to the usb devices tab.

Comment: Nothing there :(. Should I turn my atention to pci devices ?

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks very much like you have a broken usb sub system. Although you do have a usb device plugged in, it might be a laptop and plugged in internally instead of a usb connector on the outside.

From the looks of things, it looks like some kind of touch device, maybe a touchpad or touchscreen. But it also has plenty of other inputs for buttons. Or course all of that may be bogus if the usb sub system in dying.